# Recursively list neighbors of a node in tree/directed graph, for all nodes in graph, one "level" at a time?

Tags: pandas, networking, graphviz, python-3.7, dot

I am trying to generate a graph of a "commission sharing" organization from an Excel sheet with two columns, and numerous rows. The left row contains the unique ID assigned to each agent. The right row cells list the unique ID of the agent who recruited the agent in the cell to the left. I manually inserted a new row 1 with the values:
agent and hired_by

I converted the excel data into a pandas Edgelist using:

```
import pandas as pd
XL='path to Excel file'
df=pd.read_excel(XL,sheet_name=3)
G=nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df,'agent','hired_by',create_using=nx.Graph)
```

For these purposes it is important to use nx.Graph rather than nx.DiGraph, because "direction of connection" is not important. All that is important is the "level," i.e., how many hops between the root node and the agent, for purposes of determining compensation attributes.

I can then use the following code to determine the hierarchies from root by level, which can then be pasted into a working .dot (directed graph) file, with few edits. Where by working I mean it separates the levels graphically, because it consists of lines like:

"node01" -> {"node02", "node03", "node04", "node05", "node06"}

```
for n in G.nodes():
if len(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n)) == 1: 
print(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n),len(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n)))
```

This produces output like:

```
"node01" -> {"node02", "node03", "node04", "node05", "node06"} 1
...
"node06" -> {"node10", "node11", "node07"} 2
...
"node17" -> {"node21", "node22"} 4
```

This works well enough, the only problem is that I have to manually change the number "1" in the code above for each level, and copy and paste the output into my .dot file, and then rearrange the lines because the output does not group all of the 'level 3s' together.

This is an acceptable level of kludge for now, but I may have many more records to process.

Is there any way to make this work recursively, from level to level?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this question still relevant?

Comment: Yes. Could show me how to do recursion on the following code, instead of having to increment the node numbers by hand:
```
//read_excel, then convert_to_pandas_edgelist as Agraph not directed graph
//
///then:

for n in G.nodes():
    if len(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n)) == 1:  /// I manually incremented this value
        print(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n),len(nx.shortest_path(G, 'node01', n)))

Comment: I'm going to edit original post per site guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in getting the agents who were hired by each of the other agents based on a data set with columns "agent" and "hired_by" (like the first flat list you present), you can do that with a group statement like his:

```
# case 1: directly hired
df_work.groupby('hired_by').agg(dict(agent=list))
```

Now if you want to get a list of indirectly hired people in the sense that agent 1 of your example hired agents 2-8 (4, 5, 7 and 8 indirectly). Then you could try the following code (again `df` is the origin dataframe):

```
# case 2: directly and indirectly hired
df_work= df.copy()
# add a distance since you mentioned, you want to know the "level"
df_work['distance']= 1

# construct a flattened data frame in which the
# relationship indirectly-hired-by is resolved
old_size= 0
new_size= df_work.shape[0]
# loop as long as the size doesn't change 
# (btw. it's guaranteed to terminate because
# you have a finite set of agentoyees, and thus
# also only a finite but maybe large number
# of distinct result records)
while old_size != new_size:
    # the size changed, so try again
    df_merged= df_work.merge(df_work, left_on='hired_by', right_on='agent', suffixes=['_agent', '_hired'])
    df_merged['distance']= df_merged['distance_agent'] + df_merged['distance_hired']
    df_merged.rename({'agent_agent': 'agent', 'hired_by_hired': 'hired_by'}, axis='columns', inplace=True)
    df_work= pd.concat([df_work, df_merged[['agent', 'hired_by', 'distance']]], axis='index', ignore_index=True, sort=False)
    # now get rid of the duplicates (ignoring the distance)
    df_work.drop_duplicates(['agent', 'hired_by'], keep='first', inplace=True)
    old_size= new_size
    new_size= df_work.shape[0]

# now construct the lists
df_work.groupby('hired_by').agg(dict(agent=list))
```

The last group returns the list of directly and indirectly hired agents for all agents who hired anyone.
The logic needs `log_2(max_depth)` steps to build the flattened representation, where `max_depth` is the longest path from an agent to the agent who indirectly hired him (I think you would call it the maximum level).

If this logic is applied to your test data:

```
raw="""1 1
2 1
3 1
4 2
5 3
6 1
7 2
8 3"""

import io
df= pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(raw), sep='\s+', dtype='Int64')
df.columns= ['agent', 'hired_by']
```

The output is:

```
# case 1: directly hired
df.groupby('hired_by').agg(dict(agent=list))
Out[1]: 
                agent
hired_by           
1         [2, 3, 6]
2            [4, 7]
3            [5, 8]

# case 2: directly and indirectly hired
Out[2]: 
                            agent
hired_by                       
1         [2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8]
2                        [4, 7]
3                        [5, 8]
```

In case, you need it formatted as in your example, you can wrap it like this:

```
for hired_by, agents in df_work.groupby('hired_by').agg(dict(agent=list)).iterrows():
    print('{hired_by} -> {agents}'.format(hired_by=hired_by, agents=', '.join(map(str, agents['agent']))))

# case 2: directly and indirectly hired
1 -> 2, 3, 6, 4, 7, 5, 8
2 -> 4, 7
3 -> 5, 8
```

Comment: I got this to work with some adjustments. Thank you for your time in working on it. However, I could not figure out how to use the "levels" in pd_work or pd_merged.

Comment: I got some use out of this. Thank you for your time in working on it. However, I could not figure out how to use the "levels" in pd_work or pd_merged, which I need to apply Graphviz attributes in the .dot file (such as node size/color) based on 'level.'

I think this could be done by moving the pandas data into a networkX digraph, and recursively querying based on list(DG.predecessors('NameOfNode') and counting how many times that needs to be done until arriving at the "root" node. But I could not figure out how to make that work either. Still, thanks for your excellent help!

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it. What do you want to do with the levels? Doesn't it hel to use `df_merged['distance']` for your purposes?

Answer (score 0):

If you have your directed graph already created, (call it `G`), you may use the following code to achieve what you're looking for:

```py
from collections import defaultdict


recruit_dict = defaultdict(set)

# Use .edges instead of nodes to get connections between nodes
for agent, recruited in G.edges:
    if agent == recruited:
        continue
    recruit_dict[agent].add(recruited)

with open("dot.txt", "w") as out_handle:
    for parent, children in recruit_dict.items():
        children_str = ', '.join(
            f'"{child}"' for child in sorted(children)
        )
        out_handle.write(f"\"{parent}\" -> {children_str}\n")
```

Contents of `dot.txt` given your sample input:

```
"1" -> "2", "3", "6"
"2" -> "4", "7"
"3" -> "5", "8"
```

Comment: @TTG Do you actually have a `networkx.DiGraph` object that is constructed the way you suggested you have it? If you do, it should simply "work" without any change (except for the variable name).